# What is wrong when trying to find how much bytes sent(uploaded) so far?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an event where i'm doing a progress report to backgroundworker1 progresschanged event:

```
mbSent = ((double)obj.BytesSent) / (1 << 20);
stringProgressReport[2] = mbSent.ToString();
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, 2);
```

mbSent is a global double var. And stringProgressReport is string array var.
I have also a var type long called totalBytes that is the file i'm uploading size.
But i'm not using this var here maybe i should.

Then in the backgroundworker progresschanged event i did:

```
label5.Text = stringProgressReport[2];
```

The problem is in label5 i see it just counting like int numbers 1,2,3,4,5...when it's getting to 25 in the end i see the number 25 become 25.34543356767 and the totalBytes size is something else at all it's 26.7898 or something.

Something wrong with this: mbSent = ((double)obj.BytesSent) / (1 << 20);
Maybe i need to sue here somehow the totalBytes(The file total size) ?

This is how i'm calculating the totalBytes:

```
long totalBytes = 0;
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "mp4 files (*.mp4)|*.mp4|All files (*.*)|*.*";

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                FileNameToUpload = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                FileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(FileName))
                {
                    totalBytes = fileStream.Length;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: totalBytes to double = 26.5765107025313792 ?

Comment: Note that the way you're reporting the progress isn't thread-safe - you can't just update a field from one thread and read it from another. Instead, create some object that contains all the information you want to report, and pass it as the second argument to `ReportProgress`.

Comment: Luaan can you show me an example with my code how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your calculation.  If you don't want to see any decimals in your output either don't convert `mbSent` to a double or use a format string in your `ToString()` call.

Either:

```
mbSent = obj.BytesSent / (1 << 20);
```

Or:

```
stringProgressReport[2] = mbSent.ToString("D");
```

And  when `totalBytes` is 26,789,800, mbSent will be 25.45874420 is completely correct.  20,789,800 / 1,048,576 = 25.45874420.

Comment: shf301 when i'm doing: mbSent = ((double)obj.BytesSent) / (1 << 20);
            stringProgressReport[2] = mbSent.ToString("D"); i'm getting exception on the ToString("D") Format specifier was invalid

Comment: System.FormatException occurred
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=Format specifier was invalid.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Number.FormatDouble(Double value, String format, NumberFormatInfo info)
       at System.Double.ToString(String format)
       at Youtube_Manager.Form1.videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(IUploadProgress obj) in d:\C-Sharp\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\Form1.cs:line 108
  InnerException:

Comment: Looks like that's not supported on doubles.  "N" or "N0" should work.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx